# How to get the assembly version from .XLL(When a DLL is converted to XLL)

Tags: vba, excel-dna

I converted  dll (of a VB.NET project) to xll using ExcelDna.Does the xll carry the assembly version in it? If not..How can I version a .xll file? Once I do this, I have to get the assembly version programatically in VBA code..Would appreciate help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the version information for your .dll, your code could do something like

```
Dim myAssemblyName As AssemblyName = _
    new AssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
Dim myVersion As Version = myAssemblyName.Version
```

To access this from VBA, you could make a hidden UDF in your add-in that you call from VBA using `Application.Run`.

The .xll has it's own version information and is not automatically updated from the .dll that you embed. You can use the ['verpatch' Version Resource Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) to update the version information of the .xll, as was [discussed on the Excel-DNA Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_frm/thread/1aeb03c92d127f45).

If you want to read the .xll version that was updated by 'verpatch' from VBA, you be calling the WIN32 version API from VBA, which is discussed in [KB article 139491](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139491).

Comment: Thats a good suggestion.For some reason  my VB.net project(to which I added ExcelDna package) stops producing .xll file after working on it for some time..I cleared the cache in Temp folder also..What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: It even says ExcelDnaPack.exe stopped working...But it did this after I worked for some time.I have seen in many posts that the .dll ,.xll and some other files have to be in the same directory..I am not clear on this...Would really appreacite help...

Comment: Best is to post the output of ExcelDnaPack to the Excel-DNA support group on Google Groups: http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna